# Datastax consistency

Tags: datastax, consistency

We've installed Datastax on five nodes with search enabled on the five nodes and replication factor of 3. After adding 590 rows to a table and select from node 1 it retrieve 590. And when selecting from other nodes the number varies from 570 to 585 rows.

I tried using CONSISTENCY QUORUM on cqlsh, but nothing changed. And solr_query is not supported on CONSISTENCY QUORUM.

Is there a way to assure all data written to Cassandra is relieved as it is?

Comment: if you want to ensure consistency, the formula is (nodes_written + nodes_read) > replication_factor. You can read about that [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html)

Comment: Thanks LHWizard, regarding my case the nodes_written are five and nodes_reads are five also? Or how can I calculate them?

Comment: you typically specify consistency level (CL) in your client, so if you WRITE at CL = quorum, then at least 2 nodes (that's a quorum when your RF = 3) must acknowledge the write. If you then READ at CL = quorum, at least 2 nodes must acknowledge the request in order for it to succeed. Here we have nodes written = 2 and nodes read = 2 with RF=3. Therefore 2 + 2 > 3 and consistency is assured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As LHWizard mentioned, if you use Consistency levels such that (nodes_written + nodes_read) > RF, you will ensure immediate consistency.

In your case, you can try using a CONSISTENCY ALL on your read so that all nodes are checked before returning (this will be immediately consistent even with write CL of ONE). This should actually trigger a read repair on the inconsistent nodes and the missing data will be streamed to those nodes.

You're right that solr queries can only be read at CL ONE. If you need higher consistency requirements, you will need to raise the CL for the writes to achieve what you need.

Comment: Thanks Alec, how can I raise the CL for writes? Is the CL for writes differs from replication factor?

Comment: Yes, consistency level is set at query time. You set it like you mentioned in your question, typing CONSISTENCY QUORUM, CONSISTENCY ALL, CONSISTENCY ONE, etc into cqlsh. List of levels is here http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html